# How to draw the probability distribution curve for this situation?

Tags: probability

It's a real-world problem I am working on. We need to distribute 10 grand prizes in between 200,000 users who will join the platform in next 30 days and the remaining users will get some small prizes.

The prizes are numbered from 1 to 10 and the prize numbered 10 is awarded to user number 10. What was be the probability of this happening? Similarly, what will be the probability of 11th user winning the 10th grand prize and so on up till 200,000th user. And is there a way to plot this?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are you asking about the event "each of the first $10$ players wins a grand prize"?  Or the event "the prizes are numbered from $1$ to $10$ and the prize numbered $10$ is awarded to user number $10$"?  Or something else altogether?

Comment: yes the prizes are numbered from 1 to 10 and the prize numbered 10 is awarded to user number 10. What was be the probability of this happening?

Similarly what will be the probability of 11th user winning the 10th grand prize and so on uptil 200,000th user. And is there a way to plot this?

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify your question, don't leave critical information for the comments.  In any case, prize $\#10$ is equally likely to go to any user, so the distribution is uniform.

Comment: I guess, when they're giving the tenth prize, then they're essentially uniformly choosing between $199~991$ people.

Comment: Do you know the exact number of users when you select the prize winners, choose the winners and then allocate in order of arrival?  If so, and are selecting $10$ from $200000$ with equal probability, the probability all ten go to $10$ people in the first $n$ is $\frac{n \choose 10}{200000 \choose 10}$.  This is a cumulative probability so you need to take differences to get the probability mass function to answer your second question and use  $n=10$ to answer your first

Comment: Do you know the exact number of users when you select the prize winners - the 10 prizes will be distributed to 200,000 users randomly @Henry

Comment: @Henry it makes sense. Just confirming for 2nd question, for 11th user getting the prize probability will be (11C10-10C10)/(200000C10)? and similarly for 12th onwards will need to subtract the previous numerators?
.

Comment: Yes - that is my reading of your question